# Getting latest date with count of customers in R

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
Date_X <- c('2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-04-01','2020-05-01','2020-06-01')
Showroom <- c('A','A','A','A','A','A')
Item <- c('z1','z2','z3','z2','z2','z3')
Customer <- c('c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6')
Quantity <- c(12,23,34,22,11,234)
df <- data.frame(Date_X,Showroom,Item,Customer,Quantity)
```

I want to see the total number of customers that have brought a particular item at a particular showroom in the last 6_days. For example; Total numbers of customers buying item 'z2' from showroom 'A' in the last 6 days are 3 and the average quantity is (23+22+11)/3. It should also have the latest date of purchase at showroom-item level. [Note: The actual data has 100+ showrooms and 1000+ items]

The output desired is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Showroom, Item) %>% summarise(Total_Customers = n(), Quantity = mean(Quantity)) %>% 
   left_join(df %>% group_by(Showroom, Item) %>% filter(Date_X == max(Date_X)), by = c('Showroom', 'Item')) %>% 
       select(Showroom, Item, Total_Customers, 'Last_Purchase_Date' = Date_X, 'Quantity' = Quantity.x)
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'Showroom' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   Showroom [1]
  Showroom Item  Total_Customers Last_Purchase_Date Quantity
  <chr>    <chr>           <int> <chr>                 <dbl>
1 A        z1                  1 2020-01-01             12  
2 A        z2                  3 2020-05-01             18.7
3 A        z3                  2 2020-06-01            134
```

Comment: Can we also add another column with shows total number of days that item was sold in a store?

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table` is to group by 'Showroom', 'Item', summarised by taking the number of rows (`.N`) for 'Total_Customers', `last` value of 'Date_X' (assuming the 'Date_X' is ordered) and the `mean` of 'Quantity'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Total_Customers = .N, 
      Last_Purchase_Date = last(Date_X),
      Quantity = mean(Quantity)), by =  .(Showroom, Item)]
#   Showroom Item Total_Customers Last_Purchase_Date  Quantity
#1:        A   z1               1         2020-01-01  12.00000
#2:        A   z2               3         2020-05-01  18.66667
#3:        A   z3               2         2020-06-01 134.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `transform` + `aggregate`

```
transform(
  aggregate(. ~ Showroom + Item, df, c),
  Date_X = sapply(Date_X, tail, 1),
  Customer = lengths(Customer),
  Quantity = sapply(Quantity, function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
)
```

which gives

```
  Showroom Item     Date_X Customer  Quantity
1        A   z1 2020-01-01        1  12.00000
2        A   z2 2020-05-01        3  18.66667
3        A   z3 2020-06-01        2 134.00000
```